# Regular expression: extract everything before comma or all text if no comma, except a specific digit comma digit combination

Tags: python, regex

I have a series of strings from whom I want to extract a part:

| string | match |
| --- | --- |
| difluoroethane, HFC-152a | difluoroethane |
| difluoroethane HFC-152a | difluoroethane HFC-152a |
| 1,1-difluoroethane, HFC-152a | 1,1-difluoroethane |
| 1,1-difluoroethane HFC-152a | 1,1-difluoroethane HFC-152a |

basically everything before the first comma OR the entire string if there's no comma, but include in the match those cases of digit comma digit which are part of the compound name.

so far that's what I tried

```
^(.{2,}?),
```

but it only works for line 3 in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^(?:\d+,\d+)?[^,]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NWLjwQ/1/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:\d+,\d+)?`: Match an optional `digits,digits` at the start
- `[^,]+`: Match 1+ non-comma characters

Comment: works great thanks, the optional \d combo at the start was what I was missing